# Как применить popper.js к разным элементам?

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет.

Использую popper.js с jquery без bootstrap.
Как сделать так, чтобы разная кнопка вызывала разный поппер? И при клике в другое место, чтобы попер скрывался?

```
    <button class="popper"></button>
    <div class="tooltip">
    wow поппер1
    </div>

    <button class="popper"></button>
    <div class="tooltip">
   wow поппер2
    </div>

    <button class="popper"></button>
    <div class="tooltip">
    wow поппер3
    </div>
```

Тут jquery код

```
var ref = $('.popper');
var popup = $('.tooltip');
popup.hide();

ref.click(function(){
    popup.show();
    var popper = new Popper(ref,popup,{
        placement: 'top',
        modifiers: {
            flip: {
                behavior: [
                    'left',
                    'right',
                    'top',
                    'buttom'
                ]
            },
            offset: {
                enabled: true,
                offset: '0,10'
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ref.click(function(){
  var nextPopup = $(this).next(".tooltip");
  nextPopup.show();
  var popper = new Popper($(this),nextPopup,{
    ...
```